# Dynamic “filtering” list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a list of filters for a website user to filter on, such as a product category page. I'm giving the user the option to filter on brandname, model name, or gender.

To avoid serverside code I'm trying to build it clientside. So, I'm looking on the different `data-attr` and building an array of filtering values of what's actually available to filter on.

I have made it work, but I'm not sure it's the most efficient way to do it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="mix Brand_1 Model_2 Gender_0" data-Gender="0" data-Brand="Casio" data-Model=""></div>
    <div class="mix Brand_3 Model_1 Gender_0" data-Gender="0" data-Brand="Casio" data-Model=""></div>
    <div class="mix Brand_4 Model_1 Gender_2" data-Gender="2" data-Brand="Seiko" data-Model="Precision"></div>
    <div class="mix Brand_4 Model_1 Gender_1" data-Gender="1" data-Brand="Nikon" data-Model="Lada"></div>
    <div class="mix Brand_5 Model_2 Gender_1" data-Gender="1" data-Brand="DELL" data-Model="Inspirion"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
// Loop through all div's with .mix class 

var Genders = [];
var Brands =  [];
var Models = []; 
$( ".mix" ).each(function() {
   // build arrary with Gender

   if ($(this).attr('data-Gender')) {
           genderFilter = $(this).attr('data-Gender');
            var found = jQuery.inArray(genderFilter, Genders);
       if (found >= 0) { } else {
                // Element was not found, add it.
                Genders.push(genderFilter);
            }
   }
   // build arrary with Models
    if ($(this).attr('data-Brand')) {
           brandFilter = $(this).attr('data-Brand');
            var found = jQuery.inArray(brandFilter, Brands);
       if (found >= 0) { } else {
                // Element was not found, add it.
                Brands.push(brandFilter);
            }
   }
   // build arrary with Brands
    if ($(this).attr('data-Model')) {
           modelFilter = $(this).attr('data-Model');
            var found = jQuery.inArray(modelFilter, Models);
       if (found >= 0) { } else {
                // Element was not found, add it.
                Models.push(modelFilter);
            }
   }
});

console.log( Models.length );
console.log ( Models);
console.log( Brands.length );
console.log ( Brands);
console.log( Genders.length );
console.log ( Genders);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6ksLwts/)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You passed through the "First Post" queue with flying colors!

Answer (score 1):

It is customary to use lowercase names for variables and Capitalized names for classes, so I would rename `Genders -> genders`, and likewise the `Models` and `Brands` arrays too.

---

The `if` blocks are a bit tediously written. They would be better this way:

```
var genderFilter = $(this).attr('data-Gender');
if (genderFilter) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(genderFilter, genders) == -1) {
         // Element was not found, add it.
         genders.push(genderFilter);
    }
}
```

Btw, note that when you retrieve `data-Gender="0"` using `.attr('data-Gender')`, it's treated as the string `"0"`, and in `if ("0") { ... }` it evaluates to true, so the `genders` array will have the values 0, 2, 1. Perhaps you might want to use `.data('genders')` instead, in which case the `genders` array will have the values 2, 1.

For models and brands, using `.data('model')` instead of `.attr('data-Model')` will give the same result, so I suggest using the simpler.

---

For genders, models, brands, you do essentially the same thing.
This calls for a helper function:

```
function addToArrayIfNew(arr, item) {
    if (item && jQuery.inArray(item, arr) == -1) {
        arr.push(item);
    }
}
```

With this, you could simplify the entire code like this:

```
$( ".mix" ).each(function() {
    addToArrayIfNew(genders, $(this).attr('data-Gender'));
    addToArrayIfNew(models, $(this).data('model'));
    addToArrayIfNew(brands, $(this).data('brand'));
});
```